# EL 3.1 in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat

I am very new to J2EE and Web services, so my question can very well be considered easy/obvious for seasoned folks!.
I am trying to update from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8. [Migrating to Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Specification_APIs), says,
"Apache Tomcat 8 supports the Java Servlet 3.1, JavaServer Pages 2.3, Java Unified Expression Language 3.0 and Java WebSocket 1.1 specifications. The changes between versions of specifications may be found in the Changes appendix in each of specification documents."

I want to upgrade the existing configuration as per the new specification. 
Can someone give me directions as to which files I need to look at?

Comment: What existing configuration?

Comment: @Gimby configuration as in ?

Comment: That's what I'm asking you. You are the one vaguely referring to an existing configuration in your question.

Comment: @Gimby, I agree I must be vague, because I'm quite aware of Java stuff. Would you point to something specific, so that I could go back, search for it and post it here?